# Why is wd.switch_to.default_content() not returning to original webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gecko

I'm making an image scraper for bing because it has a well developed search by license function.
In anycase I can't seem to get more than one image because I can't get back to the main page after switching to the iframe to get the src from the first image. Any tips?

```
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    
    image_url = []
    
    wd = webdriver.Firefox()
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)

    ##search bing for images
    search_url = f"https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat%20clipart&qs=n&form=QBIR&qft=%20filterui%3Alicense-L1%20filterui%3Aimagesize-large&sp=-1&pq=good%20clipart&sc=8-12&cvid=493F746CDC7B4E70BF3BEDDA3CF674E1&first=1&scenario=ImageBasicHover"
        # load the page
    wd.get(search_url)
    
    thumbnail_result = wd.find_element_by_css_selector("img.mimg")
    
    thumbnail_result.click()
    
    wait.until(
            EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "OverlayIFrame"))
        )
    wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.nofocus"))
        )
    
    actual_image = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('img.nofocus')
    
    image_url.append(actual_image.get_attribute('src'))

    ##This is where it doesn't switch back to the original webpage    
    wd.switch_to.default_content()
```

Here is the code with the changes you suggested:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

image_url = []

wd = webdriver.Firefox()

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)

search_url = f"https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat%20clipart&qs=n&form=QBIR&qft=%20filterui%3Alicense-L1%20filterui%3Aimagesize-large&sp=-1&pq=good%20clipart&sc=8-12&cvid=493F746CDC7B4E70BF3BEDDA3CF674E1&first=1&scenario=ImageBasicHover"
    # load the page
wd.get(search_url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.mimg"))).click()

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "OverlayIFrame"))
    )
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.nofocus")))

actual_image = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('img.nofocus')

image_url.append(actual_image.get_attribute('src'))

print(image_url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#close"))).click()

wd.switch_to.default_content()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.mimg"))).click()
```

Comment: `wd.switch_to.default_content()` not return you back to main page .It is used to come out from `iframe`.You need to click on `close` button to close the image page.Once you click on that you'll see main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wd.switch_to.default_content()` not return you back to main page .It is used to come out from `iframe`.You need to click on `close` button to close the image page. Once you click on that you'll see main page

```
image_url.append(actual_image.get_attribute('src'))

#Click on close button to go back to main page
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#close"))).click()

##Now jump out from iframe
wd.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: @KuuduK I get this error message:selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <img class="mimg" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.JgwgOdMAdRu0WIxqmknq6wHaIF?w=179&h=196&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7"> is not clickable at point (99,323) because another element <iframe id="OverlayIFrame" class="insightsOverlay" name="cat clipart - Bing images - details" src="about:blank"> obscures it

Comment: Use  `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.mimg"))).click()`

Comment: Got another error: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <img class=" nofocus" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.JgwgOdMAdRu0WIxqmknq6wHaIF?pid=Api&rs=1"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed